# File handles not working properly in Perl

Tags: perl, file, filehandler

I tried initializing two file handles to NULL and later use it in my program.

This was my code:

```
my $fh1 = " ";
my $fh2 = " ";
open($fh1, ">", $fname1);
open($fh2, ">", $fname2);
print $fh1 "HI this is fh1";
```

After executing, my files contained this:

fname1 is empty

fname2 cointains

```
Hi this is fh1
```

What was the mistake ?

Why is fname1 empty while fname2 contains a string, even though I haven't  inserted any string in fh2?

Comment: Have you tried this with `use strict ; use warnings;` ? It is throwing the error in open call.

Comment: When I run you code I get this: `syntax error at fh.pl line 3, near ", >"
syntax error at fh.pl line 4, near ", >"
Execution of fh.pl aborted due to compilation errors.`

Comment: They're *file HANDLES*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set `$fh1` and `$fh2` to the same value (a space character, not NULL) and so they refer to the same underlying typeglob for I/O.

Filehandles in Perl are a special variable type called a glob or typeglob. In the old days of Perl 4, you always referred to a glob as a character string, often as a bareword. The barewords `STDIN`, `STDOUT`, and `STDERR` are relics of this simpler time.

Nowadays, you can (and usually should) use lexical filehandles, but the underlying reference to a typeglob will still be there. For example, you can write

```
my $fh = 'STDOUT';
print $fh "hello world\n";
```

and this will do the exact same thing as

```
print STDOUT "hello world\n";
```

Now if you pass an uninitialized scalar as the first argument to `open`, Perl will assign an arbitrary typeglob to it. You probably don't need to know which typeglob it is.

But if the argument to `open` is already initialized, Perl uses the typeglob with that argument's value. So this snippet of code will create and add data to a file:

```
my $fh = "FOO";
open $fh, '>', '/tmp/1';
print FOO "This is going into /tmp/1\n";
close $fh;
```

Now we can look at your example. You have set `$fh1` and `$fh2` to the same value -- a string consisting of a space character. So your `open` call to `$fh1` creates an association between a typeglob named `" "` and the file descriptor for the output stream to `$fname1`.

When you call `open` on `$fh2`, you are reusing the typeglob named `" "`, which will automatically close the other filehandle using the same typeglob (`$fh1`), the same was as if you say `open FOO, ">/tmp/1"; open FOO, ">/tmp/2"`, the second `open` call will implicitly `close` the first filehandle.

Now you are printing on `$fh1`, which refers to the typeglob named `" "`, which is associated with the output stream to file `$fname2`, and that's where the output goes.

It was a mistake to initialize `$fh1` and `$fh2`. Just leave them undefined:

```
my ($fh1, $fh2);
open $fh1, ">", ...   # assigns $fh1 to arbitrary typeglob
open $fh2, ">", ...   # assigns $fh2 to different arbitrary typeglob
```

Comment: You can even write `open my $fh1 , '>' , '...' or die "Cannot write: $!\n";`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't initialise your file handles at all, otherwise Perl will try to use that value as a file handle instead of creating a new one. In this case you have opened `$fname1` on the file handle `' '` (a single space) and then opened `$fname2` on the same file handle, which closes `$fname1`.

Rather than declaring the file handles separately, it is best to declare them in the `open` statement, like this

```
open my $fh1, '>', $fname1;
open my $fh2, '>', $fname2;
```

then there is less that can go wrong